# How to implement SwipeRefreshLayout on a CardView inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, cardview

**RecentNewsFragment.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final String TAG = "MainPageActivity";

    final RecyclerView rvNewsArticle;

    final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recent_news, container, false);

    rvNewsArticle = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvNewsArticle);
    rvNewsArticle.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rvNewsArticle.setLayoutManager(manager);

    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.primaryColor, R.color.primaryTextColor, R.color.secondaryColor);

    String url = "http://192.168.0.29/theflare/app/news.php";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response);

                ArrayList<News> newsList = new JsonConverter<News>()
                        .toArrayList(response, News.class);

                final NewsArticleAdapter adapter = new NewsArticleAdapter(getActivity(), newsList);

                rvNewsArticle.setAdapter(adapter);

                swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                rvNewsArticle.setAdapter(adapter);
                                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            }
                        }, 2500);
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    );

    MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

    return view;
}
```

As you can see, this is the code that I have built for my `CardView`. Unfortunately, my `SwipeRefreshLayout` does not work. (It works, but animation only, and does not refresh the view.) Have I put the `setOnRefreshListener` on the wrong place or am I just missing something here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: **Issue** : you are just refreshing it (showing animation) and after `2.5` seconds you just disable the animation using `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);` but there was no request executed inside `onRefresh`. so execute request `onRefresh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your callback methods in the wrong place. You should create a new request in the `onRefresh()` method, not the other way around.

```
private static final String NEWS_URL = "http://192.168.0.29/theflare/app/news.php";

private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

@Override
public view onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ...

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            loadNews();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void loadNews() {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                ArrayList<News> newsList = new JsonConverter<News>().toArrayList(response, News.class);
                NewsArticleAdapter adapter = new NewsArticleAdapter(getActivity(), newsList);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I had to put a `loadNews();` inside the `onCreateView` to be viewed in a `Fragment`. But overall, this was a big help, really! Thanks again!

Comment: @MatthewMiranda Glad to help. It is perfectly fine to have the `loadView` code within `onCreateView`. I only separated it to avoid duplicate code (usually you end up calling the same code to initially load the data and to refresh the data). A `Fragment` should not prevent you from doing this.